# Jsoup getting a hyperlink from li

Tags: java, jsoup

I have

```
<div id = top1>
   <div id topsub1>
   <ul class="student">
   <li>
    <a href="/thomas">Tom</a>
    </li>
    </div>
   <div id topsub2>
   <ul class="student">
   <li>
    <a href="/thomas1">Tom1</a>
    </li>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to get the href and text
So I did 
Elements xx= select (div div ul li)

when I do foreach xx for y and if I do

string1= y.text(); //This is printing Tom
String2= y.attr("href") //This is always empty. I am not able to get /thomas?
I also tried y.attr("a[href]"))

and also what is :
doc.select(".studentnames > a");?
does this mean that on the ID=studentnames get all the "a" correct???

Comment: Your html code looks messed up with the naked div's. Consider editing this and reposting html code that makes more sense and is easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you simply did `Elements eles = doc.select("a[href]");`? Also I believe that when using the `attrib(...)` method, you don't pass in the tag, just the attribute name itself.

edit:
You state:

> the issue with doing doc.select("a[href]..there are many many attributes and hrefs..i want only that is next to student name..thats why i am doing immediately after I do text so that I can get - name of student and his website

Then refine result returned by your select by calling multiple selects sequentially or chaining them:

```
Elements eles = doc.select("ul.student").select("a[href]");
```

or perhaps (I've never done this):

```
Elements eles = doc.select("ul.student a[href]");
```

or even:

```
Elements eles = doc.select("div > div > ul.student > li > a[href]");
```

Comment: the issue with doing doc.select("a[href]..there are many many attributes and hrefs..i want only that is next to student name..thats why i am doing immediately after I do text so that I can get - name of student and his website

Answer (score 0):

This is your error:

**1.** Your first select only get `div div ul li`, so that `Elements` contains `li` tag(s) only. So you can do either of the following way:

**Get each element**

```
for (Element x: yy) {
  Element aTag = x.child(0);
  // or it can be aTag = x.select("a[href]").first();
  // Do your stuff here !
}
```

**Get from the select query:**

```
Elements yy = doc.select("div div ul li a[href]");
```

I want to mention that, please do not use **`Element.text()`** is to get the data inside tags, so in this case, it is the `li`. While debugging, you should use **`Element.html()`** or **`Elements.html()`**.

**2. About your concern:**

> and also what is : `doc.select(".studentnames > a")`? 
>   does this mean that on the ID=studentnames get all the "a" correct???

**`.`** is class, whereas **`#`** is id.
Furthermore, **`>`** is **direct child**.

So your query means that: *"return all the a tag which is a **direct** child of a tag which has **class equals 'studentnames'**"*

For more specific about it, you should check [Jsoup's `Selector`'s document](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)