# GetValue (JSoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div class="Class-feedbacks">
  <div class="grading class2">
    <div itemtype="http://xx.edu/grading" itemscope="" itemprop="studentgrading">
      <div class="rating">
        <img class="passportphoto" width="1500" height="20" src="http://greg.png" >
        <meta content="4.0" itemprop="gradingvalue">
      </div>
    </div>
    <meta content="2012-09-08" itemprop="gradePublished">
    <span class="date smaller">9/8/2012</span>
  </div>
  <p class="review_comment feedback" itemprop="description">Greg is one the smart person in his batch</p>
</div>
```

I want to print:

```
date: 2012-09-08
Feedback : Greg is one the smart person in his batch
```

I was able to use this as suggested at - [Jsoup getting a hyperlink from li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443298/jsoup-getting-a-hyperlink-from-li)

The `doc.select`(div div divn li ui ...) and get the class feedback.

**How should I use the select command to get the values of the above values?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute, use the `attr` method. E.g.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("meta");
for(Element e: elements)
  System.out.println(e.attr("content"));
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Mine is a complex page with so many divs. so I am using the selector as = doc.select("div div div div div div div.Class-feedbacks). so how can I get both the feed back and also date? the logic you explained me is to get one information only? I need both ..pl correct me

Comment: For the feedback element you can use `doc.select("div div div div div div div.Class-feedbacks p.feedback").text()`.

Comment: Actually for this I have to do do selects? is there way I can get better using one select..the isue with this when I tried initially is : I have to write both these in a arrays (2 arrays) I have print from array1= date and arry2= feedback. so I was looking how to get this one select so that I save some processing

Comment: I don't think you can do it using a single select.

Answer (score 0):

In one single select ...have you tried the comma Combinator "," ?
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

```
Elements elmts = doc.select("div.Class-feedbacks meta, p")

Element elmtDate = elmts.get(0);
System.out.println("date: " + elmtDate.attr("content"));
Element elmtParag = elmts.get(1);
System.out.println("Feedback: " + elmtParag.text());
```

You should get back 2 elements in your list the date and the feedback after the select.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I might be late, but if anyone else wants to know how to do this easily, the below code will be helpful.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
// We select the meta tag whose itemprop property has value 'gradePublished'
String date = doc.select("meta[itemprop=gradePublished]").attr("content");
System.out.println("date: "+date);
// Now we select the text inside the p tag with itemprop value 'description'
String feedback = doc.select("p[itemprop=description]").text();
System.out.println("Feedback: "+feedback);
```